# How to update sql table using edit fields?

Tags: java, android, jquery, sql

I have list view activity:

```
public class List extends ActionBarActivity{

private CustomCursorAdapter customAdapter;
private PersonDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
private static final int ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private ListView listView;

private static final String TAG = List.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    databaseHelper = new PersonDatabaseHelper(this);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(List.this, Edit.class);

                intent.putExtra("id", position);                               

                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    listView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return false;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
    }); 
    // Database query can be a time consuming task ..
    // so its safe to call database query in another thread
    // Handler, will handle this stuff for you <img src="http://s0.wp.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif?m=1129645325g" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley">

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(List.this, databaseHelper.getAllData());
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
    });
}

    public void onClickEnterData(View btnAdd) {

      startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, Permission.class), ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);

}

    public void onClickLogOut(View btnLogOut){
   Intent intent = new Intent(List.this,
           MainActivity.class);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   startActivity(intent);
   }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        databaseHelper.insertData(data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_name"), data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_surname"),data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_enterdate"),data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_entertime"),data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_exitdate"),data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_exittime"));

        customAdapter.changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllData());
    }
 }
  }
```

This is my SQL helper :

```
public class PersonDatabaseHelper {

private static final String TAG = PersonDatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

// database configuration
// if you want the onUpgrade to run then change the database_version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";

// table configuration
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table";         // Table  name
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "_id";     // a column named "_id" is required for cursor
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME = "person_name";
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_SURNAME = "person_surname";
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERDATE = "person_enterdate";
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERTIME = "person_entertime";
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITDATE = "person_exitdate";
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITTIME = "person_exittime";

private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

// this is a wrapper class. that means, from outside world, anyone will communicate with PersonDatabaseHelper,
// but under the hood actually DatabaseOpenHelper class will perform database CRUD operations 
public PersonDatabaseHelper(Context aContext) {

    openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(aContext);
    database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

   public void insertData (String aPersonName, String aPersonSurName, String aPersonEnterDate,String aPersonEnterTime, String aPersonExitDate,String aPersonExitTime) {

    // we are using ContentValues to avoid sql format errors

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, aPersonName);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_SURNAME, aPersonSurName);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERDATE, aPersonEnterDate);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERTIME, aPersonEnterTime);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITDATE, aPersonExitDate);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITTIME, aPersonExitTime);

    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

}

  public Cursor getAllData () {

    String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

    return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
 }


// this DatabaseOpenHelper class will actually be used to perform database related operation 

private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
        super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        // Create your tables here

        String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_SURNAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERDATE + " TEXT," + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERTIME + " TEXT," + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITDATE + " TEXT," + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITTIME + " TEXT )";

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Database schema upgrade code goes here

        String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

        Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);       // drop previous table

        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);               // create the table from the beginning
    }
}
}
```

This is my Custom adapter class

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // when the view will be created for first time,
    // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_item, parent, false);

    return retView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // here we are setting our data
    // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views

    TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

    TextView textViewPersonsurName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.surName);
    textViewPersonsurName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));

    TextView textViewPersonEnterDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
    textViewPersonEnterDate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(3))));

    TextView textViewPersonEnterTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
    textViewPersonEnterTime.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(4))));

    TextView textViewPersonExitDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date2);
    textViewPersonExitDate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(5))));

    TextView textViewPersonExitTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time2);
    textViewPersonExitTime.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(6))));
}
  }
```

This is how my list looks like:
[image]

and then i click list item i have created class :

```
public class Edit extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if(extras !=null)
    {
    int id = extras.getInt("id");

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                      "Position :"+id , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }

    EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);     
    EditText surName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.surName);       
    EditText date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date2);        
    EditText time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time2);        
    EditText eDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date3);       
    EditText eTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time3);

}

 public void onCancel(View btnCancel){
Intent intent = new Intent (Edit.this,List.class);
startActivity(intent);
  }
 public void onSave(View btnSave){

  }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
 }
```

after click it looks like that : 
[image]

So i manage to get column id by just clicking it, but the main problem is that i want to make when i click on list item all info is shown in edit text fields (now its empty as i uploaded the image) and after i click add button it updates SQL table and info shown in the list. 
List.java store my list and Edit.java where empty edit fields apear after an item click in listview.

EDIT: CustomCursorAdapter

```
 public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // when the view will be created for first time,
    // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_item, parent, false);

    return retView;
}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // here we are setting our data
    // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views

    TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

    TextView textViewPersonsurName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.surName);
    textViewPersonsurName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));

    TextView textViewPersonEnterDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
    textViewPersonEnterDate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(3))));

    TextView textViewPersonEnterTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
    textViewPersonEnterTime.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(4))));

    TextView textViewPersonExitDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date2);
    textViewPersonExitDate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(5))));

    TextView textViewPersonExitTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time2);
    textViewPersonExitTime.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(6))));
}

public Person get(int position) {
    Cursor cursor = getCursor();
    Person person;
    if(cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        person = new Person();
        person.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME));
        person.surname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_SURNAME));
        person.enterDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERDATE));
        person.enterTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERTIME));
        person.exitDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITDATE));
        person.exitTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITTIME));
    }
    return person;
}
  }
```

Edit xml:

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   </EditText>
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/usersurname"
    android:hint="Surname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  </EditText>



 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/date2"
    android:hint="Enter date"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  </EditText>
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/time2"
    android:hint="Enter time"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  </EditText>
  </LinearLayout>   
  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >  
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/date3"
    android:hint="Exit date"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   </EditText>
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/time3"
    android:hint="Exit time"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   </EditText>
   </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickSave"
        android:text="Add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:onClick="onCancel"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</LinearLayout>


   </LinearLayout>
```

Edit3:

```
public class Edit extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText name;
EditText surName;
EditText date;
EditText time;
EditText eDate;
EditText eTime;
String data_name;
String data_surname;
String data_enterdate;
String data_entertime;
String data_exitdate;
String data_exittime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
     data_name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
     data_surname = intent.getStringExtra("surname");
     data_enterdate= intent.getStringExtra("enterdate");
     data_entertime = intent.getStringExtra("entertime");
     data_exitdate = intent.getStringExtra("exitdate");
     data_exittime = intent.getStringExtra("surname");


     name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
     surName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.surName);
     date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date2);
     time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time2);
     eDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date3);
     eTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time3);


     setText();

}

 public void setText(){
name.setText(data_name,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
surName.setText(data_surname,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
date.setText(data_enterdate,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
time.setText(data_entertime,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
eDate.setText(data_exitdate,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
eTime.setText(data_exittime,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
 }
public void onCancel(View btnCancel){
Intent intent = new Intent (Edit.this,List.class);
startActivity(intent);
 }
 public void onSave(View btnSave){

 }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
  }
```

Comment: I think you forgot to explain your problem? if you can explain what were you trying and what was not happening, that will be great.

Comment: I explained after last image

Comment: In short terms i want to make list view item Editable and later update it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first. You can put all the column with the intent like you put the id. For example if you want to put the name, then:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(List.this, Edit.class);

        //change this to your actual code
        String name = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position).getName();
        intent.putExtra("id", position);  
        intent.putExtra("name", name);
        //put the rest of the data here
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In your `Edit` activity, just call:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String data_name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
//get the rest of the data
```

Then set the text to the appropriate EditText:

```
name.setText(data_name);
```

If you want to update the SQL table, just make a method in your `DatabaseOpenHelper` to update the columns. If you don't know how to, just do a Google Search on SQLite update statement for Android.

Then add an onClickListener to your button:

```
yourAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //get an instance of the DBHelper class and get
              the text from the EditTexts to update the table
        }
});
```

EDIT:

Make this `Person` class

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String surname;
    String enterDate;
    String enterTime;
    String exitDate;
    String exitTime;
}
```

EDIT 3:

This should be the proper way to deal with `CursorAdapter`, sorry because I haven't used it before.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);
Intent intent = new Intent(List.this, Edit.class);

Person p = new Person();
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) customAdapter.getItem(position);
p.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_name"));
p.surname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_surname"));
p.enterDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_enterdate"));
p.enterTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_entertime"));
p.exitDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_exitdate"));
p.exitTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_exittime"));

//get the rest of the attributes
intent.putExtra("id", position);  
intent.putExtra("name", p.name);
intent.putExtra("surname", p.surname);
//put the rest of the data here
startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

EDIT 4:

```
public class Edit extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText name;
EditText surName;
EditText date;
EditText time;
EditText eDate;
EditText eTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
     String data_name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
     String data_surname = intent.getStringExtra("surname");
     String data_enterdate= intent.getStringExtra("enterdate");
     String data_entertime = intent.getStringExtra("entertime");
     String data_exitdate = intent.getStringExtra("exitdate");
     String data_exittime = intent.getStringExtra("surname"); //typo here


     name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username); //corrected
     surName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usersurname); //corrected
     date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date2);
     time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time2);
     eDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date3);
     eTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time3);

     name.setText(data_name);
     surName.setText(data_surname);
     date.setText(data_enterdate);
     time.setText(data_entertime);
     eDate.setText(data_exitdate);
     eTime.setText(data_exittime);
}


public void onCancel(View btnCancel){
finish();
 }
 public void onSave(View btnSave){

 }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
  }
```